PostgreSQL database on port 5432 not visible in Adminer running on port 8080
I am working with a local setup that includes a PostgreSQL database and Adminer for database management. My PostgreSQL database is running on port 5432, and Adminer is running on port 8080. However, when I access Adminer, I am unable to see the database on port 5432.
Here’s my setup:

PostgreSQL: Running on localhost:5432
Adminer: Running on localhost:8080
Backend server: Running on port 3777
Use Docker for this setup.
TypeORM is used to manage the database.

I've verified that PostgreSQL is running on port 5432 by using psql and connecting successfully. I've also checked that Docker containers for both Adminer and PostgreSQL are running. In Adminer, I’ve tried entering localhost as the server and 5432 as the port, but the database doesn’t appear and an error appeared:

Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Is there something I’m missing in the configuration that could be causing Adminer not to connect to the PostgreSQL instance? I'll appreciate any guidance or troubleshooting steps.

On docker, each container is its own 'localhost'.  You need to talk to other containers using their assigned network "host" names.
